# Marshal an array of floats to an array of structs without copying?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, marshalling

Suppose I have the following code

```
public static class Main
{
    public struct Vec3
    {
        public float x, y, z;
    }

    public void Entry()
    {
        float[9] floats = new floats[9] { 1f, 2f, 3f, 4f, 5f, 6f, 7f, 8f, 9f };
        Vec3[3] vecs;
    }
}
```

I want to convert the float[] to a Vec3[].

Is there a way to do this with Marshaling such that the copying required would be faster than iterating over the float[] and copying each float to the Vec3[]? Assume float[] is very large.

Comment: Your `Vec3` is actually more than just 3 floats in memory. Information about the object itself is also stored there. That's why I don't think it's possible to do it this, but I'll be happy if someone prove me wrong.

Comment: I believe c# structs can be marshaled in a way that allows them to be passed to c++ API functions and so this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` class to do this:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (Vec3* vecsPointer = vecs)
    {
        Marshal.Copy(floats, 0, new IntPtr(vecsPointer), floats.Length);
    }
}
```

That said, I think it's generally better to avoid `unsafe` if possible, even if there's some measurable performance difference. It would have to be a pretty significant performance improvement for me to choose the above over a straight managed copy (which in a Release build is probably pretty fast, though probably not as fast as the above).

For sure, you should carefully measure the overall impact of each approach and make sure it's worth the potential maintenance hassles before committing to the `unsafe` method.

EDIT: out of curiosity, I went ahead and did a simple test. I created a `float[]` 1MB in size and copied to a `Vec3[]`. I used the above, and compared that to a simple loop that looks like this:

```
for (int k = 0, l = 0; k + 2 < floats.Length; k += 3, l++)
{
    vecs[l].x = floats[k];
    vecs[l].y = floats[k + 1];
    vecs[l].z = floats[k + 2];
}
```

In my tests, I performed each copy 10,000 times per trial, for a total size of the copy of around 10GB.

The `unsafe` version "only" was about (just slower than) 2x faster than the safe version. Each 10,000 copy trial took around 1.5 seconds for `unsafe`, and 3 seconds for safe. A 2x speed-up sounds pretty good, but of course you only get that if your program is doing nothing else. In a real-world program that might translate to as little as a 5% improvement or less, depending on what else is going on.

Some other interesting things I saw:

- With Marshal.Copy(), it's a lot faster to copy an exact power of 2 than something else. E.g. 2^20 bytes versus something else. It got closer to a 3x speed-up in that case.
- Related to the above, Marshal.Copy() seems a lot more sensitive to the exact size of the copy. You get more consistent performance with safe code, albeit slower of course.
- At a small enough buffer size (seems to be around 100-200 bytes), the setup overhead of the `unsafe` code holds it back, and it's just as slow as the safe version.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer and profiling data. Very well done. This seems to be the solution even though I'd prefer something that did no copying.

Comment: As a side note. If I had a Vec3[] and I wanted to call an unmanaged function that took a float* (float array) and a size using PInvoke. Is there a way to do that without copying? What is wrong with doing "var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(vecs, GCHandleType.Pinned); APICall(handle.AddrOfPinned(), sizeof(float) * 3 * vecs.Length);"?

Comment: Yes. If you don't mind having the object pinned (which will interfere with .NET memory management) for the duration of the call, you can just pass the `float[]` directly to the unmanaged code. You can just use the same `fixed` syntax, I think...you shouldn't have to go through the `GCHandle.Alloc()` method as long as you only need the object pinned in a limited scope. That said, 10GB/s seems pretty fast to me; what little additional speed you might get from passing the array directly, you might just lose somewhere else by blocking GC operations. You'll want to do thorough testing, at least.

Comment: @BrianReichle: `Buffer.BlockCopy()` is (indeed, all of the `Buffer` members are) limited to use with arrays of primitive types. It won't work with the user-defined struct `Vec3`.